# Informatica DB2 DSN not working in Designer

Tags: db2, odbc, informatica, informatica-powercenter, dsn

I am trying to connect to DB2 database to import source structure. I tried using ODBC DB2 Wire Protocol Driver Setup. I provided IP Address, TCP Port, Location ( DB2 to Z/OS and Iseries), but when I click on test connection I get below error:

[Informatica][ODBC DB2 Wire Protocol driver][DB2]NULLID.DDOS510A DOES NOT HAVE PRIVILEGE TO PERFORM OPERATION PACKAGE ON THIS OBJECT.

Same method I tried in  lower environment of DB2 and connection works. but in higher environment I get this error. ( I verified login in the database directly and my user id has login access).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question, it is about configuration.

The reason that it works on one database, but fails on another, is because only one of the databases has the correct permissions.

Ask the DBA to grant relevant privileges to the userid at the database.

You will find more details at the following IBM [technote](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21693243) and also at [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21623849).